# How do you get the raw address of a function?

Tags: c++, c, assembly

I'm writing a Jit compiler and I need to call a function based on its (offset) address from assembly. IE, given:

```
void myfunction() { }
```

I want to be able to get the actual address for this function so I can call it by offset from assembly. I've tried a couple of things, but I get different answers:

```
void *address1 = (void *&)myfunction;
void (*address2)() = &myfunction;

cout << &address1 << endl; // 0x7fff5fbff800
cout << &(*address1) << endl; // 0x20ec8348e5894855
cout << &(address2) << endl; // 0x7fff5fbff808
```

Which of those is correct (if either of them is)? If there is an easier way I'm overlooking, definitely interested in that as well.

**Update**

I did the smart thing and did an `objdump`, which says:

```
000000010000fd70 <__Z10myfunctionv>:
10000fe76:  48 8d 05 f3 fe ff ff    lea    -0x10d(%rip),%rax        # 10000fd70 <__Z10myfunctionv>
```

so the correct answer appears to be:

```
cout << (void *)(void (*)())myfunction << endl; // 0x10000fd70
```

Per Eric below, this is the best answer:

```
cout << hex << (uintptr_t)myfunction << endl;
```

Comment: `&(*address1)` is not valid C++ where `address1` is type `void*`.

Comment: Maybe, but it gives the correct answer.

Comment: I think I second Andreas on this one. That seems the only one that gives a reasonable answer.

Comment: Also isnt it valid in c to dereference void?

Comment: What's the output of `std::cout << address1;` ?

Comment: @CaptainObvlious No good, just gives me `1`.

Comment: `address2` does contain the address you want. Don't assume that the output of `std::cout` is correct. Cast to a `void*` is necessary.

Comment: Just do `std::cout << (void*)function;`

Comment: @CaptainObvlious: which is equal to address1 (address1 == (void *)address2).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no standard way to do this in C++, because the standard does not define any conversions from pointers to integers or to non-function pointers or any behavior for printing function pointers other than interpreting them as true/false, and function pointers are always true (non-null). Function pointers are not intended to be printed or exported from a program.

In C, you may convert a function pointer to `uintptr_t` and print that:

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
…
    printf("0x%" PRIxPTR "\n", (uintptr_t) myfunction);
```

Some C++ implementations will allow you to cast function pointers to other types of pointers or to integer types. You should ensure the conversions performed by these casts are supported by the C++ implementation(s) you are using before relying on them. In some implementations, the value of a function pointer might not be the address of actual code; it might be the address of a descriptor of the function. In that case, branching to the address would not work; you need to conform to the platform’s requirements for calling functions.

Printing the address of a function for further use in other programs is rarely likely to be of any use. Using the printed address to call the function typically requires recompiling the program with new code that uses the address derived from the printing, and changing the program and then recompiling may change the address of the function. The usual way that a function would be called from assembly is that its address would be provided to assembly code other via the normal linking mechanisms (refer to it by name in assembly and let the linker resolve the reference) or by passing a pointer to the function to the assembly routine as a parameter.

Another option is to place the function in a dynamic library, in which case its address can be looked up by features of the dynamic loader, such as the `dlsym` routine.

Answer (score 2):

To get the memory address of a function, use the function name without parentheses.

```
void f(); 
void (*p_fun)() = f;
```

You may optionally include an ampersand:

```
void f(); 
void (*p_fun)() = & f;
```

So, for your question, `address2` is pointing to the function, to print out its address, use

```
cout << address2 << endl;
```

Comment: This only seems to give me the address of the pointer to the function, not the function itself.

Comment: `&address2` is the address of the variable `address2` and not the address of the thing that `address2` is referring to

Answer (score 2):

The correct one is

```
 cout << &(*address1) << endl; // 0x20ec8348e5894855
```

the same would be

```
 cout << address1 << endl;
```

The other two are referring to the addresses of the function pointer, i.e. the variable adress1 and address2.

Comment: You're getting downvoted (not by me), but I get the sense this is correct.

Comment: I found the correct answer in my updated original post above, but now I wonder what 0x20xxxxxxxx refers to then?

Comment: I downvoted by mistake, I will make a trivial edit so I can remove the downvote.

Comment: -1. There is no valid way to dereference a `void*` in C++. As long as `address1` is type `void*` your answer is wrong.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious: well, that was a citation from the original question. Obviously this expression uses a c++ compiler extension (in C99 void pointers are treated like char pointers and this is legal) with little ambiguity on the semantics. I don't see why claiming this is "wrong" is relevant for the original question.